# Pop everything but maximum from a list

Tags: python, list, max

I have a list of up to several thousand entries and their values:

```
lst = [
    [entry1, [value1, value2, value3]],
    [entry2, [value4, value5, value6, value7]],
    ...
]
```

Need to pop everything but the maximum from the values of each entry.

Would you know a smooth way of doing so?

Comment: show your efforts. Unclear, what is `entry1`, a scalar value, a tuple, a dict?

Comment: Also, a dictionary seems more appropriate here (given that `entry1, .., entryn`) are unique.

Comment: Dictionary was my initial idea. But since Py3 doesnt allow me to index over values later on, have dropped that. The entries are int-s (but not necessarily), the values are floats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't pop, replace the lists:

```
lst = [[entry, [max(values)]] for entry, values in lst]
```

This replaces the *whole list* with a new one. If you have existing references to all those sublists that need to see the change, then you could assign to the `[:]` slice for each, in a `for` loop:

```
for _, values in lst:
    values[:] = [max(values)]
```